# focus() method and event order (in pure JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, events, asynchronous, focus, synchronous

I am currently working on a large web project with a sophisticated help system and therefore need an in-depth understanding of when events are fired synchronously or asynchronously, respectively.

Actually, I am fighting with the focus() method which I use at many places and which does not seem to work like it is documented everywhere. I have read (some parts of) the W3C DOM specifications and many articles and tutorials, and all of them tell the same. When we call element.focus(), the following should happen:

1) The cursor (caret) is set to the respective element.

2) All event handlers which handle the focus event for the respective element are called in a synchronous (blocking) manner, i.e. it is guaranteed that all of these handlers are called before the elem.focus() returns. In other words, it is guaranteed that *none* of these handlers will be called *after* elem.focus() has returned.

When developing my application, I have relied on that behavior, but it now seems that (at least) IE11 and Chrome don't obey these rules. I think I could understand what is going on if somebody could follow the steps below and answer my final question.

First, please consider the following HTML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de" lang="de">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>

    <input type="button" value="click me" />
    <input type="text" />

    <script>

    function ButtonHandler(e) {

      alert('in onclick')
      text.focus()
      alert('out onclick')    
    }

    function FieldHandler(e) {

      alert('onfocus')
      text.onfocus = null
    }

    var button = document.body.children[0]
    var text = document.body.children[1]

    button.onclick = ButtonHandler
    text.onfocus = FieldHandler

  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I have got parts of the code from here: http://javascript.info/tutorial/events-and-timing-depth. The author uses that code to prove that elem.focus() indeed works synchronously. To keep things simple, let us use IE11 for showing my problem.

Please load the HTML document as shown above into IE11. Then click anywhere into the white area of the page to get the focus out of the text input, and then hit reload. You now should have a freshly loaded document with the text input being unfocused.

Now, when you click the button, you will get three alerts: in onclick, onfocus, out onclick (in that order). This seems to prove that elem.focus() behaves synchronously.

Now consider the following HTML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de" lang="de">

<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/xhtml+xml; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
</head>

<body>

    <input type="button" value="click me" />
    <input type="text" />

    <script>

    function ButtonHandler(e) {

      console.log('in onclick')
        text.focus()
        console.log('out onclick')    
    }

    function FieldHandler(e) {

      console.log('onfocus')
        text.onfocus = null
    }

    var button = document.body.children[0]
      var text = document.body.children[1]

      button.onclick = ButtonHandler
      text.onfocus = FieldHandler

  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

It is exactly the same document as the first one, with the following exception: I have replaced alert() by console.log().

Now, please load that document into IE11 and open IE11's console. Again, get the focus away from the text input and reload the document, then click the button. The console now shows the following lines (in that order):

```
in onclick
out onclick
onfocus
```

This seems to prove that the call to elem.focus() is done *asynchronously* (the focus handler clearly is called *after* elem.focus() has returned), and this is a great problem for my application.

Could please anybody explain to me why exactly elem.focus() seems to be synchronous in the first document, but asynchronous in the second one?

By the way, I am using IE11 here because I have been able to find the example above which is very easy to understand. I hope somebody will give a general answer to my question and that I am not told that it is just a misbehavior of IE11.

Firefox seems to be the only browser which does it right, Chrome fails even with the first document. I already knew that browsers don't obey DOM specifications in that the event order and the order in which event handlers are called is wrong in many cases. But I have been pretty sure (until now) that at least methods which are specified as blocking are indeed called in a synchronous manner ...